# Use assignment operators instead of an implicit constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, implicit, assignment-operator, explicit

In my program, I am trying to use the assignment `operator=` to assign an object of my class. I am specifically trying to call the assignment operator instead of an implicit constructor (thus the `explicit` keyword). When I try to compile, I get a [C2440 Compiler Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2440?view=msvc-160):

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
    explicit MyClass(double x = 0.) :
        m_x(x) {
    }

    MyClass& operator = (const double& other) {
        m_x = other;

        /* do something special here */

        return *this;
    }
private:
    double m_x;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass my_class = 2.; // C2440

    return 0;
}
```

I guess that the compiler fails trying to call the constructor implicitly (because of `explicit`). Does anyone have a fix?

Comment: Would `MyClass my_class; my_class = 2.;` be an acceptable solution?

Comment: `Does anyone have a fix?` Remove `explicit`? What is there to fix - everything working as intended - compiler is failing code that should be failing. How do you want to fix it?

Comment: `MyClass my_class = 2.;` is more or less equivalent to `MyClass my_class(2.);`, but, you said that it in `explicit`, which makes that invalid.

Comment: @ChrisMM That is explicit so ... go for that as an answer - even though it doesn't use the assignment operator

Comment: There is no operator in `MyClass my_class = 2;` so hiding the constructor will never magically make a call to an assignment operator.  According to the C++ grammar, this is a variable definition with a copy initialization.  It doesn't become some other grammar production just because your constructor is declared explicit (although C++ has stateful grammar, so things *can* parse differently, this example doesn't)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyClass my_class = 2.;` is more or less equivalent to `MyClass my_class(2.);`, but, you marked the constructor as `explicit`, which prevents C++ from doing that automatically.

So, in the way you've written your code, you cannot really do what you want. You could explicitly call the constructor using:

```
MyClass my_class(2.); // Explcitly call your constructor
```

Or, as Ted Lyngmo mentioned in the comments, you can do:

```
MyClass my_class; // Call your constructor with default argument of 0
my_class = 2.; // then call your assignment operator
```